# Compounded if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to python, I cannot get the following simple compounded if statement to work

```
if A == B & C >= D & C <= E:
```

each of the sub statements works on there own but I can't seem to combine them together in one command.

Comment: `&` is a [binary bitwise operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations), not the logical `and`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if A == B and C >= D and C <= E:
```

Answer (score 0):

`&` is a [binary bitwise operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations), not the [boolean operator `and`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) you are looking for.

Do this:

```
if A == B and C >= D and C <= E:
```